# Android App - listView is not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm new to Android App programming and tried to include a ListView to my Test-App but it's not working. I don't know if the ListView is invisible or not even initialized.

The Activity Code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
ListView lview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonClick);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.list_array);
    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);
    lview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}

View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
};
}
```

The Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Close Activity"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Array XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="list_array">
        <item>Im learning Android</item>
        <item>Yeaaay programming is fun</item>
        <item>OMG</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I really don't understand why the ListView doesn't show up because i followed a step-by-step tutorial. Hope someone could help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example of me. it works fine. just change/add your content

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_functions);



        String[] functions = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"};

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, functions);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.functionsListView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
    }

}

XML: activity_functions.xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/functionsListView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok all i changed was to add "String[] functions = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"};" and that worked. But its not working with the array in my arrays.xml. Why??

Comment: Ok it works for me now:
I changed String[] functions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_array);
Didn't know that R.array.list_array returns an int. Why is it like that?

Comment: R is auto create file and it contains integers. like id.

Comment: Perfekt! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the ListView a height of "match_parent".

You currently have it as "wrap_content", but because it's a scrolling view, it has no way to calculate it's children's size, so it collapses to 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

Things i noticed:  `new ArrayAdapter<String>(...)`
ArrayAdapter is generic.

In XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Okay i added the <String> to ArrayAdapter and changed the XML .. Now only a white box is visible, but no content. Am i correctly loading the array?

Comment: set height of the listview on match-parent too

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your second_layout.xml. It should have `match_parent` height and your listview should have height in dp or have it `match_parent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Close Activity"
android:textSize="30sp"
/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you call wrong constructor.

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
```

before assigning ArrayAdapter, get array from resource, for example

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xxxx.xml);
```

and use below constructors of one

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)

ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```